# MongoDB Merge Query Results From two Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, collections

I'm novice to MongoDB. Looking for something similar to UNION in SQL for MongoDB.
So I have two collections with similar structure. I need to run two different queries on each of them but the results returned will be in the same format, is it possible to join them together?

Collection1:

```
db.Questions.findOne(){
"QuestionId" : 29,
"Title" : "What's an easy-to-use tool to manage datasets?",
"CreationDate" : 20130500000000.0,
"OwnerUserId" : 37,
"AcceptAnswer" : 34,
"AcceptDate" : 20130900000000.0,
"Tags" : "tool-request,analysis",
```

}

Collection 1 Return format:
    { "QuestionId" : 29,
    "CreationDate" : 20130900000000.0}

Collection2:

```
db.Answerss.findOne(){
"Id" : 8,
"ParentId" : 7,
"CreationDate" : 20130500000000.0,
"Accepted" : "N",
"OwnerUserId" : 41
```

}

Collection 2 Return format:
    { "Id" : 8,
    "CreationDate" : 20130500000000.0}

Is there a way to merge these two results? I feel it has sth to do with JavaScript language, array, combined with $push function. But I am not so sure how to do that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before I answer comprehensively, do actually want to join ($lookup in MongoDB language) answers to the questions?   Or are the operations truly separate?   The Id:29 suggests a join...?

Comment: truly separated. so no $lookup. Sorry the id should not be identical, just the format is the same. Thanks,